# How to restrict the default AWS VPC ingress to block all traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have a VPC that gets created through CloudFormation, but it also creates a default Security Group with inbound and outbound access. I don't use this default security group, and would like to restrict it. I can't find anywhere that gives me a good reference on how to lock it down through CloudFormation. Egress I have setup, but not Ingress. The best I can do is to manually remove it once it's created, but I'm hoping to find a config that will do the same when it gets created. This is what I have, but I don't know if it's effective. How do I completely block all ingress and egress for this SG?:

```
    "VPCDefaultSecurityGroupIngress": {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
      "Properties" : {
        "GroupId": { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["Vpc", "DefaultSecurityGroup"] },
        "CidrIp": "127.0.0.1/32",
        "IpProtocol": "-1"
      },
      "DependsOn" : [
        "Vpc"
      ]
    },
    "VPCDefaultSecurityGroupEgress": {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress",
      "Properties" : {
        "GroupId": { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["Vpc", "DefaultSecurityGroup"] },
        "CidrIp": "127.0.0.1/32",
        "IpProtocol": "-1"
      },
      "DependsOn" : [
        "Vpc"
      ]
    },
```

Comment: Have you found a resolution. I am interested in the solution as well.

Comment: Not yet. Running Fugue tomorrow on this config to see if it still complains or not.

Comment: Fugue still viewed this configuration as open and not secured.